# Conjugate functions - general definition and understanding

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems, legendre-transformation

I am currently studying Stephen Boyd, where the conjugate function is defined to be $f^*(y) = \underset{x \in Dom(f)}{sup} (y^Tx-f(x))$.

I understand the definition, but when I search for more resources online, I find something called Legendre transform, which is defined as $\displaystyle{f^{*}(x^{*}) = \sup _{x\in I}(x^{*}x-f(x)),\ \ \ \ x^{*}\in I^{*}}$, where $f$ is convex.

These definitions seem exactly the same, except for the condition on $f$.

Also, now I think about the conjugate of complex numbers and the conjugate of complex functions, which are defined to be the same quantity, but with an inverted sign of the imaginary part.

There are also conjugate pairs (Lagrangian and Hamiltonian) in physics, which rely on similar concepts.

I am guessing they are related closely. Could you help me understand these cohesively and what general conjugate functions are?

References:
[https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)

https://som-course.github.io/opt-fall-2021/static_files/Notes/lecture3.pdf

https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Conjugate_function

[https://www.math.utah.edu/~cherk/teach/12calcvar/dual.pdf](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Echerk/teach/12calcvar/dual.pdf)

Comment: This concept of function conjugation has nothing to do with complex conjugation. As far as I remember, when $f$ is convex it turns out that $f^{**}=f$. A very good read is [https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1147](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1147).

Comment: I see. So is the conjugate function defined in Boyd, a generalisation of the Legendre transform to all functions (not exclusively convex) ?

Comment: Yes. Can you give a more precise reference to Stephen Boyd's book or paper ? I have also seen conjugations of the form $\inf(f(x)-y^\top x)$ and them being defined for concave functions as well.